Fastest way to compute union of sets using Python
What is the fastest way to compute union of multiple sets in Python? Any libraries can be used.
Thanks for any input.

The question seems too broad. Can you provide some context? A [mre]?

As a general answer, np.union1d is the fastest, but this is not always the case if the input is sorted or if the values are integers with a limited range. Please provide an example that matches your input as closely as possible.
